# Convert DateFormat of even columns of a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, type-conversion, strftime

I have a Dataframe with dates in the even columns. The date format is yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss and I want to convert it to yyyy-mm-dd.
I trued by filtering the even columns and using dt.strftime like this:

```
even_cols = range(0, df.shape[1], 2)
df.iloc[:, even_cols] = df.iloc[:, even_cols].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

but i get this error

"AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dt'"

Comment: The dt accessors is a method of pd.Series not pd.Dataframes, you are trying to apply the dt accessor to more that one column at a time.

Comment: huh I undertand now why it's not forking.. what should I do then? iterate?

Comment: Use syntax like this: `df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`

Comment: still not working, I am not starting from row2 of all even columns, I can't use column names because they are not know beforehand  `df.iloc[2:, even_cols] = df.iloc[2:, even_cols].apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`

Comment: Look at the example below.  Run that and see if it works, then try to modify to fit your situation.

Comment: Hrm.. what you are doing with 2: makes little sense, you are trying to change the dtype of part of a column?  Is the dtype of the original column already a str or datetime?

Comment: Maybe you should create some sample data and expected output, this will help with gettng you the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=10),'B':pd.date_range('2018-02-01', periods=10),
                'C':pd.date_range('2018-03-01', periods=10),'D':pd.date_range('2018-04-01', periods=10)})

even_cols = [1,3]
df.iloc[:, even_cols] = df.iloc[:, even_cols].apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Output df.info():

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 4 columns):
A    10 non-null datetime64[ns]
B    10 non-null object
C    10 non-null datetime64[ns]
D    10 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), object(2)
memory usage: 400.0+ bytes
```